# Web view doesn't refresh

Tags: view, lotus-domino

I've a web view that doesn't refresh after some background operations, i need to open it in Notes Client and press ctrl+shift+f9 to achieve this.

This not always happen on production, only for some installations.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen that too and sometimes had to add `view.refresh()` code to refreshes the view after changes. Thing to check:

- Make sure view indexing option is *Auto, after first use*
  or *Automatic*.
- View may get corrupted. Add a *updall* program task to rebuild the problem view every weekend.
- Make sure the Indexer task is running on the server.